# How to write batch seperate lables (functions)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a batch file which has 3 function in it. Everything else works fine but when the first function called it runs all 3 functions, when the 2nd function is called it runs the 2nd one and 3rd, and when 3rd one is called it just runs 3rd function only because its the last function.

whats wrong with it?

code:

```
IF NOT #%1#==## GOTO END
:

IF #%1#==## GOTO HELP
:

IF NOT #%2#==## GOTO TOOMANY
:

:HELP
ECHO ** Input parameter is missing **
ECHO Correct format: %0 filename_tempate
ECHO Example: %0 *.TXT
ECHO.
ECHO Try again


:END
ECHO **End of Display**

:TOOMANY
ECHO **Too much data supplied**
GOTO HELP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `:HELP` and `:END` are not really functions, they are labels. When you use `GOTO HELP`, cmd will just jump to `HELP` and continue running the script from there. One way to  solve this problem is to put `GOTO` another label after each function. For example:

```
:HELP
ECHO ** Input parameter is missing **
ECHO Correct format: %0 filename_tempate
ECHO Example: %0 *.TXT
ECHO.
ECHO Try again
GOTO START

:END
ECHO **End of Display**
GOTO NEXT

:TOOMANY
ECHO **Too much data supplied**
GOTO HELP

:NEXT
```

This way, after cmd runs whatever is in the function, it will go to the intended location and not continue running the next function.

Another way:

```
IF NOT #%1#==## CALL :END
:

IF #%1#==## CALL :HELP
:

IF NOT #%2#==## GOTO TOOMANY
:

:HELP
ECHO ** Input parameter is missing **
ECHO Correct format: %0 filename_tempate
ECHO Example: %0 *.TXT
ECHO.
ECHO Try again
GOTO :EOF

:END
ECHO **End of Display**
GOTO :EOF

:TOOMANY
ECHO **Too much data supplied**
CALL :HELP
GOTO :EOF
```

This way, cmd will only look at the function and return to where it was earlier.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't test this code but I read it carefully. NOW I get it, I must redirect to another label like NEXT, so function won't execute any more, and the NEXT label must be at the last of all the codes, so it has no where to go. :) Thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Batch will transfer execution to the label specified, but unlike pascal and similar languages, does not regard a label as an 'end-of-procedure' - it just charges on through the label.

To exit from the program, you need to execute a

```
goto :eof
```

where the colon is `required` and the label `:eof` is understood to be 'end of file' and does not have to be declared (indeed, should not be IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

Shell scripts (batch files) don't really have functions. Goto labels are simply jump targets. Once you jump to a label, execution will continue from that line and continue until it reaches another goto or hits end-of-file. This means that when you use this line:

```
GOTO HELP
```

The script will jump to that line and run every line after that.

To work around this problem, use

```
goto :EOF
```

after your labeled sections. The :EOF means "end of file".

Bill